# pointer confusion - error: passing argument 1 of ‘value’ from incompatible pointer type; note: expected ‘...’ but argument is of type ‘...'

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure

EDIT: This was so obvious, I have no idea how I didn't notice. Thanks for your help, guys!

I am making a symbol table using binary tree in C, and I got stuck while defining the basic functions. I have never been able to fully grasp pointer operations, and these errors are making my head hurt and I have no idea how to fix them, although I'm sure that many of you will find my problem trivial.

I have a structure defined like this:

```
typedef struct SymTable {
    symbol_t *rootNode;
} symTable_t;
```

An initialisation function like this:

```
void initTable(symTable_t *table) {
    table->rootNode = NULL;
}
```

And in my main.c I call the function:

```
symTable_t *newTable = malloc(sizeof(symTable_t));
// check if malloc was successful
initTable(&newTable);
```

It throws these two errors when I try to translate:

```
main.c:12:12: error: passing argument 1 of ‘initTable’ 
from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  initTable(&newTable);
            ^

In file included from main.c:1:0:
sym_tab.c:18:7: note: expected ‘symTable_t * {aka struct SymTable *}’ but argument is of type ‘symTable_t ** {aka struct SymTable **}’
  void initTable(symTable_t *table) {
```

When I define initTable() like _initTable(symTable_t table)_, it only throws more errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `newTable` is of the type `symTable_t *`. When you use the address-of operator `&` as in `&newTable` you get a pointer to the pointer, or type `symTable_t **`. Very much like the error message says.

Comment: `newTable` has type `symTable_t *`, i.e. it is a pointer to a `symTable_t`.  If you take its address, you end up with a pointer to a pointer, i.e. a `symTable_t **`.  The function `initTable` doesn't want this.  It just wants a pointer to a `symTable_t`.  So remove the `&` and pass the pointer directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to a pointer to a `symTable_t` instead of just a pointer to a `symTable_t`.

Remove the `&` in this line:

```
initTable(&newTable);
```

and the error will go away.